# XML/RDF Parse in R

Tags: r, xml, rdf

I have a database made up of XML RDF files and would like to organize them into data frames in R.

Here is a sample file. What I would like is a data frame with each column being each of the node names. The body of the data frame would be the node values for that file.

How can I organize this into a data frame nicely?

I tried unsuccessfully to use `xmlParse()` and `xmlToDataFrame()` from the `XML` package.

The nodes (columns in final data frame) are `rdf:Description rdf:about` `rdf:type rdf:resources`, `ballads:exemplar rdf:resource`, `ballads:numberBalladsOnSheet`,  `ballads:identifier`, `ballads:sheetManifestationCreated`, `ballads:sheetManifestationComposedOf`.

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://ballads.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/id/sheetmanifestation/1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://vocab.ox.ac.uk/balladspec#SheetManifestation"/>      
        <ballads:exemplar rdf:resource="http://ballads.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/id/sheetitem/1"/>
      <!-- LITERAL VALUES -->


        <!--  number of ballads on sheet -->
        <ballads:numberBalladsOnSheet>1</ballads:numberBalladsOnSheet>
        <!-- identifier for the sheet manifestation -->
        <ballads:identifier>1</ballads:identifier>
        <ballads:identifier>UUID:d90706bc-a05a-46e2-a502-66365e1f63b2</ballads:identifier>
        <ballads:identifier>Allegro: b57054</ballads:identifier>
        <!-- EVENT -->
        <ballads:sheetManifestationCreated rdf:resource="http://ballads.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/id/event/74921d93-af22-4ad0-a782-c6d200dfd03e"/>
        <!-- ballad manifestation -->
        <ballads:sheetManifestationComposedOf rdf:resource="http://ballads.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/id/balladtextmanifestation/1"/>
        <!-- Imprint -->
        <ballads:sheetManifestationComposedOf rdf:resource="http://ballads.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/id/element/efeffc93-915b-48f9-9988-fc2820228251"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Is this the top of the document? See [example here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rdf.asp). As is, it is not well-formed since the *rdf* namespace is not defined. The root tag should contain something like `xmlns:rdf="..."`

Comment: I had removed the top of the document, so that I posted just the XML that I need to parse. Original document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eco9u9xz9hz6vcm/1.rdf?dl=0

Comment: [`rrdf`](https://github.com/egonw/rrdf) — ?